# PHP - Is it better to set session cache limiter to nocache or use jQuery ajax cache:false?

Tags: php, jquery, no-cache

Is it better to set session cache limiter to nocache or use jQuery ajax cache:false?

I'm using PHP with jQuery. I want to default `session.cache_limiter` to `nocache` for all my php pages that use sessions. That way I don't have to set `session_cache_limiter` for each page request.

I prefer not to set `cache:false` when making ajax calls from jQuery because it adds an extra timestamp $_GET to the request. I pass all the values of the $_GET array into MySQL. So I would have to `array_pop($_GET)` before sending to the database. Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`session_cache_limiter=none` seems more clean, but you shouldn't need it anyway. As long as the server sends the correct, noncached content with the correct accompanying headers jquery shouldn't cache anything anyway.

I never had problems because of extra caching. I did have problems when actually trying to make the browser cache my content though.